# How to disable the Elasticsearch "homepage" ("You Know, for Search")

Tags: elasticsearch

Somehow I can't find information about this. Therefore I'm forced to ask.

When navigating to the "homepage" of a node (e.g. `curl http://127.0.0.1:9300`) then Elastic shows some data about the cluster. E.g:

```
{
  "name" : "SCGrEKO",
  "cluster_name" : "bob",
  "cluster_uuid" : "krk-OsDUR1Gt7m9qcJkWJg",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "6.5.4",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "tar",
    "build_hash" : "d2ef93d",
    "build_date" : "2018-12-17T21:17:40.758843Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "7.5.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "5.6.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "5.0.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Is there a way to disable this? Or at least serve a blank page.

Comment: you can use "haproxy" and redirect the request without _search to port 80.

Comment: @hamidbayat Using a reverse proxy is actually a solution, but a bit overkill. Using a authentication plugin would be probably easier. I was hoping for a simple setting in the config :-/

Comment: it seems that this response is written in a .jar file.  I have searched all the text files for this response.

Comment: @hamidbayat Rewriting that response and compiling Elastic yourself is also a solution, but even more overkill. The code can be found in [MainResponse.java](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/e5805c961e3f220af399713a85ba484966da76ed/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/action/main/MainResponse.java) if you're interested for whatever reason.

Comment: Enabling authentication would not solve the problem, as a crawler, or worse a malicious port scanner, would still deduct that this is a response from an Elasticsearch cluster. So the reverse proxy solution is actually the best one since you can return whatever Elastic-agnostic response content you want to trump whoever is trying to reach your cluster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only enabling authentication would not solve the problem, as a crawler, or worse a malicious port scanner, would still deduct that `{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"security_exception...",` is a response from an Elasticsearch cluster and could still exploit well-known [Elasticsearch security vulnerabilities](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-13554/Elasticsearch.html).

If I was to create a malicious port scanner, I would not only query `/` but also very well known [API endpoints](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/rest-apis.html).

So in order to achieve what you need, you need both:

- **authentication**: to prevent anyone from freely accessing your cluster and doing any damage to your data
- **a reverse proxy solution**: to return whatever Elastic-agnostic response content you want to trump whoever is trying to reach your cluster

Answer (score 1):

While a proxy like nginx or HAproxy will be a possible solution, why not tackle the bigger problem: authentication. If you haven't properly secured your cluster, the `/` endpoint is the least of your worries — it only shows you the version of your cluster, while other endpoints can be used to extract, change, add, or remove data.

With the [release of 6.8.0 and 7.1.0 the default distribution of Elasticsearch provides free security](https://www.elastic.co/blog/security-for-elasticsearch-is-now-free). If you have security enabled, any unauthenticated request will be rejected (401 response code):

```
curl -XGET <URL>:9200/                                                                                    
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"security_exception",
    "reason":"action [cluster:monitor/main] requires
    authentication","header":{"WWW-Authenticate":
    ["Bearer realm=\"security\"","ApiKey","Basic realm=
    \"security\" charset=\"UTF-8\""]}}],
 "type":"security_exception",
    "reason":"action [cluster:monitor/main] requires
    authentication","header":{"WWW-Authenticate":
    ["Bearer realm=\"security\"","ApiKey","Basic realm=
    \"security\" charset=\"UTF-8\""]}},"status":401}
```

PS: I think you have the wrong port in your question. 9200 is by default the REST API while 9300 is for transport (cluster internal or for the deprecated Java Transport client).

Answer (score 0):

To your first question:

I am not aware that you can change the response body of the root URL of a node.

To your second question:

Yes, you can avoid getting the usual json element as a response by using the HTTP verb **HEAD** instead of **GET**.
Notice that by default curl uses **GET** as HTTP verb if you do not specify something else. As stated in the HTTP specification, GET will return a response body when possible. **HEAD** on the other side performs a GET without asking for a response body. (See the [W3 Method Definitions for HTTP/1.1](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html))

To make things a bit more clear here are the responses of a node accessed with GET and HEAD via Postman:

**GET**
[image]

**HEAD**
[image]

So to sum it up, you can get a "blank page" (as you stated) by accessing the URL with HTTP HEAD instead of GET.

I hope I could answer your question. If not, please give more information about the issue/use case/desired output.

Comment: Creative, but that doesn't solve the problem. Reason for disabling this page is to prevent crawlers to discover that this port uses Elastic, in case the firewall fails for whatever reason.

Comment: Can't you intercept/redirect the requests in your http server to another page that hides the information/is blank?

Comment: Using a reverse proxy is actually a solution, but a bit overkill. Using a authentication plugin would be probably easier. I was hoping for a simple setting in the config, but thanks for the suggestion.